# How to delete element with multiple elements inside form MongoDB array?

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to delete `{"category":"food","amount":{"$numberDouble":"12.0"}}` from array `expenses`

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"12"},
"chatID":{"$numberInt":"12"},
"expenses":[
   ​{"category":"food","amount":{"$numberDouble":"12.0"}},
   ​{"category":"food","amount":{"$numberDouble":"14.0"}}],
"income":[]}
```

I have tried this, it doesn't work:

```
update := bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"expenses": bson.D{{"category", "food"}, {"amount", 12}}}}
c.Coll.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"chatID": chatID}, update)
```

Result should be like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"12"},
"chatID":{"$numberInt":"12"},
"expenses":[
   ​{"category":"food","amount":{"$numberDouble":"14.0"}}],
"income":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This update operations works fine:

```
update := bson.D{{ "$pull", bson.D{{ "expenses", bson.D{{ "category", "food" }, { "amount", 12.0 }}}}}}
filter := bson.D{{ "chatID", chatID }}
updateResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Matched %v documents and updated %v documents.\n", updateResult.MatchedCount, updateResult.ModifiedCount)
```